# Safari tabs, NSPOSIXErrorDomain:24 and file descriptors

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, safari, crash, big-sur

I'm sorry for the duplicating question, I didn't see this specific platform for Apple :)

I have a serious problem with file descriptors and I have tried everything.

My laptop: MacBook Pro 13" 2018 with touchbar, i5, 16 Gb RAM, 512SSD. MacOS 11.3.1.

Recently Chrome just starts to crash without errors. I try to use Safari instead and have another problem.
When I open a new tab I get the following error: [safari error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJkwT.jpg). Sorry for screenshot in russian :)
Literal translation: Safari cannot open the page Safari cannot open the page. Error: "The operation could not be completed. Too many files are open" (NSPOSIXErrorDomain: 24). I looked for an error by error code, but no one really complained about it

**NSPosixErrorDomain:24** - Error: "Too many open files in system".

Also, javascript in browsers (Chrome and Safari) is often very slow. On some sites UI is lagging and slow, but maybe this is another problem.

To fix errors with file descriptors I changed some limits.

Default setting:

```
launchctl limit
cpu         unlimited      unlimited
filesize    unlimited      unlimited
data        unlimited      unlimited
stack       8388608        67104768
core        0              unlimited
rss         unlimited      unlimited
memlock     unlimited      unlimited
maxproc     2784           4176
maxfiles    256            10240
```

Custom settings which I tried:

```
launchctl limit
cpu         unlimited      unlimited
filesize    unlimited      unlimited
data        unlimited      unlimited
stack       8388608        67104768
core        0              unlimited
rss         unlimited      unlimited
memlock     unlimited      unlimited
maxproc     2784           4176
maxfiles    10240          10240
```

Also I checked SSD:

```
    smartctl -a disk0s2
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [Darwin 20.4.0 x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       APPLE SSD AP0512M
Serial Number:                      C02829300TNJJ5910
Firmware Version:                   1161.100
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x106b
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x000000
Controller ID:                      0
NVMe Version:                       <1.2
Number of Namespaces:               1
Local Time is:                      Tue May 25 11:31:13 2021 MSK
Firmware Updates (0x02):            1 Slot
Optional Admin Commands (0x0004):   Frmw_DL
Optional NVM Commands (0x0004):     DS_Mngmt
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         256 Pages

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     0.00W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        38 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          99%
Percentage Used:                    7%
Data Units Read:                    202 068 806 [103 TB]
Data Units Written:                 163 348 342 [83,6 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 2 319 293 376
Host Write Commands:                1 196 921 469
Controller Busy Time:               0
Power Cycles:                       141
Power On Hours:                     1 308
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   46
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      0

Read 1 entries from Error Information Log failed: GetLogPage failed: system=0x38, sub=0x0, code=745
```

I even tried to "light" reset macOS (without erase users data). It didn't help. From time to time I encounter crashes of various applications (browsers, Facetime, notification center, messages, Finder, etc.)

Finally, I can't understand, Mac OS can't manage with 40 tabs and several applications (Skype, Word, Outlook, Postman, vs code, archi, etc. ? My previous MacBook Air 2012 didn't have any problem...

Original question: https://superuser.com/questions/1651454/safari-tabs-nsposixerrordomain24-and-file-descriptors